# Filtrar por la fecha actual en angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Tengo una información que el servidor me envía, actualmente muestro toda la información pero necesito filtrar esa información por la fecha final en este caso y que solo me muestre la información del día actual.

```
<div class='col-11' *ngFor='let info of information' >
      <div>
        <div class='d-flex space-icon'>
          <span class='ml-1'>{{info.fechaFinal |  date:'dd/MM'}}</span>
        </div>
        <span class='title'>{{info.titulo}}</span>
      </div>
     </div
</div>
```

Esto es lo que se muestra actualmente en el frontend

```
15/04  informacion 1
16/04  informacion 2
15/04  informacion 3
12/04  informacion 4
12/04  informacion 5
```

Aquí el servidor ya me devuelve toda la información existente, pero solo quiero que en el front me muestre la información que tenga la fecha del día hoy.

el servidor me devuelve la fecha así:

```
2021-04-12T18:00:20.306Z
```

intente hacer un ngIf, en el ts puse un `fecha = new Date()` y con el `*ngif='fecha === info.fechaFinal'` pero no me funciona

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces new Date(), estás creando una fecha de este momento, pero no sólo incluye el día, sino la hora, minuto, segundo e incluso milésima de segundo. Pero no sólo eso, sino que aunque no fuese así, con `===` estás comprobando que las dos instancias de Date son la misma, lo que nunca va a ocurrir.

```js
const now = new Date();
console.log(now.toLocaleString());
const now2 = new Date();
console.log(now2.toLocaleString());

console.log(now == now2)
console.log(now.getTime(), now2.getTime());
```

Podrías transformar los dos valores a un string, usando el pipe `date` [programáticamente](https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate) y comparar los dos strings:

```
isToday(date: Date): boolean {
  return formatDate(now, format) === formatDate(date, format);
}
```

Comment: ya lo solucione, lo que hice fue crear dos fechas y poner una del día con las 00:00 y otra fecha del día siguiente también con las 00:00 y ya puse que si la fecha que necesito es mayor o igual a la del día y menor o igual a la del día siguiente me la mostrara